# Moving apps to another account: LVL and account key

Tags: android, android-lvl

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802062/any-problems-regarding-lvl-when-moving-apps-from-one-google-account-to-another) has been answered a long time ago but, since November 2011, key pairs are now tied to the application itself, not to the account anymore.

My current application (first published in mid-2011) is still using the old account key for LVL verifications (but the application key for in-app purchases).

I'm considering moving that app to another account, but I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with my LVL implementation (before moving): can I safely switch to the application key without caveats for my current customers?

From my understanding, there's nothing to do for in-app since I'm using the application key since the beggining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question: for apps created before that move, I missed the fact that the applications key are the same as my old account key! That should work out of the box.